# How to connect Salesforce logs output to Sematext or Elastic Search or any other Log Management system?

Tags: logging

Is there any way to connect Salesforce to log management systems without custom coding in order to track all logs of our apps in one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of [Event Monitoring](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring) can be ingested by any 3rd party search/monitoring/analysis product with a little bit of <strike>love</strike> [sweat](https://github.com/developerforce/elf_elk_docker). Note: Event Monitoring is being enhanced in Winter '20 release to include a [real-time option](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_security_em_rtem_ga.htm).